# dpkg dependency problem messengerfordesktop depends on libappindicator1 | libappindicator | libappindicator-gtk3

Tags: kali-linux, dpkg, dependencies

I'm using Kali Linux and I'm getting the error

> dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of messengerfordesktop: messengerfordesktop depends on libappindicator1 | libappindicator | libappindicator-gtk3

while writing this:

```
sudo dpkg -i messengerfordesktop-2.0.9-linux-amd64.deb
```

I tried `sudo apt-get install -f` but it says the package `messengerfordesktop` will be removed. I have tried installing these 3 packages manually as well but I'm getting this error:

```bsh
E: Package 'libappindicator1' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'libappindicator' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'libappindicator-gtk3' has no installation candidate
```

So what should I do?

Comment: Have you considered Debian or other distro more suited to beginners?

Comment: I don’t think Debian is for beginners, but I've been using Linux for a long time and, in principle, I'm already quite familiar with different distributions.

Comment: Debian is fine. But I used it in the example to make a point (Debian is often considered a difficult distro. I don't know why (mostly historical).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`libappindicator-gtk3` isn't available in Kali Linux.  `libappindicator1` and `libappindicator`  [have been removed from Kali repositories](http://pkg.kali.org/pkg/libappindicator).

You can install Messenger from [snapcraft](https://snapcraft.io/messenger-collabee):

```
sudo apt install snapd
sudo snap install core
sudo snap install messenger-collabee
sudo snap install slack --classic
sudo snap install discord
```

If you are using an old version of Kali (less than 2021.1)
then you have to run program this way:

```
snap run <application>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I didn't know that that package isn't available in Kali Linux. I also wanted to install Discord and Slack, but they have those dependencies too.

Comment: @Albert `snap install discord` and `snap install slack`... If you want to search any package then,,, search this way `snap search <package name>`

Comment: @Albert See my edit. Please.

Comment: @GAD3R In kali(only new version 2021.1) we get desktop entry when we install from snapd...!

Answer (score 1):

I searched on internet little bit. I found some answer for you. I don't know if they are helpful.

1. [Installing Facebook Messenger](https://www.tecmint.com/install-and-access-facebook-messenger-on-linux-desktop/)
2. [Facebook Messenger Linux](https://itsfoss.com/facebook-messenger-linux/)
3. [How to install messenger in linux](https://www.click4infos.com/install-facebook-messenger-in-linux/)
4. [Facebook Messenger](https://www.fosslinux.com/1124/facebook-messenger-for-ubuntu-linux-mint-and-fedora.htm)

[image]

I found `messenger-collabee`. I am not sure what it is. It may be facebook messenger also. I am not sure.

Install complete python tools

```
apt-get install python-setuptools python3-setuptools python-qt4-phonon python-qt4-phonon python3-pyqt4.phonon
```

You don't have to run above code cause, Kali has python.

Run it

```
wget https://github.com/oconnor663/linuxmessenger/archive/master.zip

cd linuxmessenger-master/
chmod +x fbmessenger
./fbmessenger
```

For you issue try by updating

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. But as I learned on Kali it cannot be done without snap.

Comment: Albert Yeah! Kali doesn't have snapd by default. That's why we have to install it.. I saw @GAD3R's answer... I think his answer is correct that's why I will tell you to mark that as an answer.. As you are new to Unix SE that's why I am giving you a picture how to mark as an answer. https://i.stack.imgur.com/RECp8.png

Comment: Thanks for picture, but I know that, I'm already quite familiar with stackoverflow